# WPF virtualizing big items

Tags: wpf, virtualization, itemscontrol

I´m binding a pretty huge collection of items to an ItemsControl.
The ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl is set to a custom usercontrol rendering the data.
The ItemControl is virtualized.

The problem now is that each usercontrol in the ItemsControl can become quite heigh. Its even possible that it becomes heigher than the actual screenheight. If that happens I´ve no chance to see the rest of the usercontrol because as soon as I scroll the next item in the collection is brought to the top of the screen and the only half shown item gets completly scrolled out of view. If I don´t use virtualization everything is obviously working fine.

Is there any way to get around this behavior and still be able to use virtualization?

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sample xaml showing what you're currently doing to achieve this? I would find it helpful to see how you are going about implementing your ItemsControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way around the behaviour, but it's not entirely pretty...  basically, it's to implement your own virtualizing panel.  As you correctly noticed, the behaviour of the built in panel is to draw from the top of the topmost item - you can't have half an item at the top of the screen.  This, basically, is because it makes the virtualization code a lot lighter weight, and in most cases it's not a problem.

You can create your own panel (derive from `VirtualizingPanel`) that doesn't have this restriction.  It's not straightforward, but it's worthwhile for the results!

In your case, if *all* of the items are fixed size and beyond the size of the screen, you may find it's not quite so complicated - a lot of the complexity comes when items are variable sizes.

Comment: I have implemented a virtualizing panel and have the variable size items problem you mentioned... do you have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Does your ItemsControl's ScrollViewer have content scrolling Set?

Edit 2: As Dan meantioned, it appears as soon as you try to get smooth scrolling, you lose Virtualization. I'm not sure what your requirements are, but a potential workaround might be something like the following:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp11.MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestApp11"
    Title="Window1" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="160">
                        <Border Height="200" Width="140" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="10" Margin="1" Background="Blue" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
            <ContentElement />
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Essentially, you can have the ItemTemplate wrap your UserControl Items inside a ScrollViewer. I didn't show it in my example, but you could bind the MaxHeight of the ScrollViewer (inside the ItemTemplate) to the the Height of your viewable area, and then the vertical scroll bar will only show up if your UserControl is too big to fit in the screen.

I can see where this might be too ugly of a solution to give to a customer however, in which case I think the only option is to go the route suggested by Dan.

Comment: I think the question is explanatory enough!

Comment: @Dan Puzey, the question is well explained, yes. However, often there are little details that can be left out that cause the problem. I personally find it beneficial to be able reproduce the issue somebody else is having, then offer assistance. I didn't intend to sound critical of the post because it didn't provide code. I simply would like to help solve the problem, and find it useful to see some of the code. (It helps me learn too seeing how other people do things)

Comment: Oh... and thanks for the down vote, I guess trying to be helpful is looked down on by some people.

Comment: @Scott: you should post such requests as a comment, not as an answer.  It's not about not wanting you to be helpful, it's about marking up or down answers that are good and valid answers for the question.  If you want to be helpful, delete your answer and repost it as a comment!

Comment: @Scott: it scrolls smoothly because you've broken the virtualization.  By putting the scrolling panel where you have, you've allowed the ItemsPanel to grow to the full height of all items.  If you use Snoop to examine your UI, you'll see that every child item is still being rendered.

Comment: @Dan Puzey: You are correct sir, I think the best solution is likely the one you have proposed in your answer. I've modified my answer to include a potential workaround if having a scrollviewer (per item) within a scrollviewer is acceptable. But you got my upvote for the best answer.

Comment: and +1 for introducing me to Snoop! That's a pretty cool tool!